# Using CMTime without rounding?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, core-media

I'm writing an application that uses AVFoundation and CMTime. I have logged the values of my `CMTime` instances created using `CMTimeMake()`. This value seems to be rounded to the nearest integer. I need a `CMTime` instance with a precise value, without rounding.

I have seen the rounding constants in the `CMTime` reference:

```
enum {
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero = 1,
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundTowardZero = 2,
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundAwayFromZero = 3,
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_QuickTime = 4,
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundTowardPositiveInfinity = 5,
   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundTowardNegativeInfinity = 6,

   kCMTimeRoundingMethod_Default = kCMTimeRoundingMethod_RoundHalfAwayFromZero
};
```

There aren't any example of how I can control which of these strategies is applied to a `CMTime` instance? Or, if this isn't the right way, how can I extract a precise value from a `CMTime` instance?

---

Edit:

I have found and tested `CMTIME_HAS_BEEN_ROUNDED()`. I passed my `CMTime` instance to this function and it returns `No` (indicating that the value has not been rounded). So why am I losing precision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for `CMTime`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html) you will see that it stores time as a rational number using a numerator and denominator. The numerator is `int64_t` while the denominator is `int32_t`.

The numerator specifies how many "ticks" have passed, and the denominator specifies how many "ticks" per second.

So 0.5 seconds can be stored as:

- 100/200: 100 ticks, 200 ticks per second
- 500/1000: 500 ticks, 1000 ticks per second
- 8/16, 8 ticks, 16 ticks per second

And so forth. The way you have done it, using

```
CMTimeMake([[Array objectAtIndex:i]floatValue], 1);
```

Is saying "there is one tick per second", and since the numerator is an integer, the float value is truncated so only the 1 is stored. Therefore you are specifying time as: `1/1`, one tick has elapsed, one tick per second, so you are actually storing *exactly* 1 second.

To fix this, it depends on what you want to do and whether you care about the timescale. [Apple recommends a timescale of 600](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW8), but if you don't care, you can just do this:

```
CMTimeMake([[Array objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]*1000, 1000);
```

That sets timescale to 1000, so 1000 ticks per second, so one millisecond per tick. It also converts the time in seconds to milliseconds. Note that it truncates the 4th digit, so if you had 1.2345 you just get 1.234 not 1.235. If that matters to you, see `roundf`.

Answer (score 0):

CMTimeMake([[Array objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]*1000, 1000);

This helped me to get exact time in milliseconds. Cheers.